# Convert from scientific notation string to float in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, scientific-notation

What's the proper way to convert from a scientific notation string such as "1.234567E-06" to a floating point variable using C#?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
Double.Parse("1.234567E-06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Comment: Will not work if the current culture's decimal separator is not `.`. So the always working approach is either using `NumberStyles.Any` or (better) force `InvariantCulture`: `Double.Parse("1.234567E-06", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Note that if you tack a .ToString() on the end of this procedure call it will return the scientific notation and not a string of only digits.  I needed to include a format string parameter ("0.0000") in the .ToString() call to make the float format correctly.

Answer (score 13):

Also consider using

```
Double.TryParse("1.234567E-06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, out MyFloat);
```

This will ensure that `MyFloat` is set to value 0 if, for whatever reason, the conversion could not be performed.  Or you could wrap the `Double.Parse()` example in a `Try..Catch` block and set `MyFloat` to a value of  your choosing when an exception is detected.

Comment: You don't want to rely on MyFloat being 0 to indicate a failed conversion, you want to rely on the bool return value.