# splliting a complex string in 3 parts

Tags: c#, string, split

I am communicating with a measurement isntrument and it returns the data in a single string. The output is like:

```
string result = "-3.546714E-10A,+0.000000E+00,+5.120000E+02\n";
```

So what I am interested to get in this string is first and second part. First part is Current in Ampere, and second is TimeStamp (measurement time).

I am trying this code but it does not work:

```
temp = result.Split(',');

tipair = new Results.TIPair();
tipair.Current = float.Parse(temp[0]);
tipair.Time = float.Parse(temp[1]);
```

Ideally I want it to be `-3.546714E-10` for current and `0` for time (time be any positive number).

**UPDATE:** I tried to do like below but I get very bad numbers (much bigger than they should be!)

```
temp = result.Split(',');

tipair = new Results.TIPair();
tipair.Current = float.Parse(temp[0].Substring(0, temp[0].Length - 1));
tipair.Time = float.Parse(temp[1]);
```

Comment: `10A` is a valuable part like 10Amper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse current using [Double.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx) and valid [Number Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx):

```
string result = "-3.546714E-10A,+0.000000E+00,+5.120000E+02\n";
var parts = result.Split(',');

double current = double.Parse(parts[0].Remove(parts[0].Length - 1),
                        NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.Number);
double time = double.Parse(parts[1],
                        NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.Number);
```

MSDN, [NumberStyles Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx):

> **AllowExponent**  Indicates that the numeric string can be in exponential notation. The AllowExponent flag allows the parsed string
>   to contain an exponent that begins with the "E" or "e" character and
>   that is followed by an optional positive or negative sign and an
>   integer. In other words, it successfully parses strings in the form
>   nnnExx, nnnE+xx, and nnnE-xx. It does not allow a decimal separator or
>   sign in the significand or mantissa; to allow these elements in the
>   string to be parsed, use the AllowDecimalPoint and AllowLeadingSign
>   flags, or use a composite style that includes these individual flags.

Comment: Thanks for details. Is it really should be DOUBLE? Because later I want to draw them on a bitmap and I think I am limited to PointF which only works with float??

Comment: You can change double to float and all would be parsed fine as well

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt know the Ampere unity in the first part...

you try to parse "-3.546714E-10A" to float.

You should first cut the "A" off with:

```
part[0].TrimEnd('A')
```

UPDATE:

check [Convert scientific to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639/convert-from-scientific-notation-string-to-float-in-c-sharp) question for scientific parse

by the way: float can handle a precision of 7 characters (which you are fully using). if you get more exact values you should use double (15-16 precision)

Comment: I tried to remove that character by substring but it gives me a biggg number. mayeb the floating points are not read correctly?

Comment: hmm dont know, i dont have a compiler under my hands right now... but something like that :)

Comment: @Sean87 : TrimEnd(), there is no such method like TrimRight()