# String conversion C#

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert from scientific notation string to float in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639/convert-from-scientific-notation-string-to-float-in-c-sharp)

Is it there an build-in function which converts string in format "2.71e+006" to a number or I have to write my custom algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Decimal [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb.aspx) method has an overload you can use:

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("2.71e+006", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

You can also do the same for a Double.