# C#: Scientific notation String to Int64 conversion failing

Tags: c#, parsing, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm getting an exception when trying to parse a number that is in scientific notation. Looking at other posts on how to do it, and I can't tell what I'm doing any differently than those.

I've tried the following:

```
System.Convert.ToInt64("1.0206e+06");

System.Convert.ToInt64("1.0206E+06");  // Uppercase 'E'
```

These result in a FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format.

I tried these:

```
Int64.Parse("1.0206e+06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);

Int64.Parse("1.0206e+06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Int64.Parse("1.0206e+06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

These all result in an OverflowException: Value was too large or too small.

Also tried with `Int32.Parse` and got the same exception and message:

```
(long)Int32.Parse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Using `Decimal.Parse` works with the same string and parameters passed to it:

```
(long)Decimal.Parse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64662/967504) suggests using this:

```
Double.Parse("1.234567E-06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Which is similar to my last example, I just accept all number styles, and that answer used a negative exponent. In fact, I fed that exact string into my examples and I still get the same exceptions.

Not sure if it matters, but I'm using Mono C#, the version that comes with Unity.

Here's the C# source file: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/unity-staging/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int64.cs. The exception is thrown on line 469 and doesn't provide me a call stack before that point. But I'm guessing the exception is created on line 355 or 372 since those match the exception type and message I'm being shown.

Comment: This is working when I run it in dotnet fiddle, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/lHWbgM

Comment: This isn't working when I run it in dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PvGfoW

EDIT: One of the two examples does work.

Comment: meant the overloads that have number styles, the first one isn't going to work

Comment: The Int64.Parse works on dotnetfiddle, but not in my project (Mono C#).

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact value being parsed?

Comment: That's what the Xamarin IDE is telling me: http://imgur.com/By3oJgN.

Also, my data source is a text file that has the same string value.

Comment: 99% you live in a wrong place :)  Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when parsing non-locale specific numeric values.

Comment: I live in the US, but I tried your suggestion anyway. I still get an OverflowException. I've edited my post to reflect this. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this is a bug with the version of Mono C# I'm using, which comes with Unity 5.5.x or earlier. Their repository [can be found here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono).

[Their implementation of `Int64.Parse`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/unity-staging/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int64.cs#L97) does not even check for the `NumberStyles.AllowExponents` flag, or handle exponents in any way. So it's going to fail when it finds the `+` symbol in the string. Basically, `Int64.Parse` when using Unity does not support exponents.

[Mono's `Int32.Parse`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/unity-staging/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int32.cs#L114) does seem to look for exponents, but still causes an OverflowException with all exponents that I give it.

[`Decimal.Parse`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/unity-staging/mcs/class/corlib/System/Decimal.cs#L735) actually does work with the same parameters as the other two, which suggests there was nothing wrong with the string or parameters, but it's just a bug in their other Parse methods. Decimal's parsing is completely different from how the Int parsing is being done, so that may explain why it works and the others don't.